# How to ask your boss politely if he has some free time

Tags: communication, india

I want to ask my boss if he has some free time. That I want to discus some work.

How can I ask it more politely?

Comment: Can you describe your relationship with your boss and where you are located?

Comment: I am located in India For me the boss is just like a formal big brother

Comment: I did update my answer with a more formal way, but I’m not from India, so there may be a more appropriate way to say it.

Comment: I suggested a change (from "is free" -> "have free time"). The first reading of the  question, I thought you were asking "how to ask my boss if he is not married".

Comment: Is there some reason why you can't just ask him when he has free time? Is he very busy? Hard to reach? What is complicating this situation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depends on your familiarity with them, but I like “hey ^boss’ name^, when you have a free few minutes, I’d like to talk to you about ^whatever^ please. Thanks!”

A more formal way might be:
“Sir, when you have a free few minutes, I’d like to talk to you about ^whatever^ please. Thank you.”

Comment: yeah...that might be good. thanks for your answer

Comment: but can you tell me more polite way to say that, because it sounds like he is buddy to me

Answer (score 1):

> Hey Mr. X,
>
> I have some questions around problem Y and I need your assistance.
>
> Are we able to discuss this at some stage, or alternatively, are you able to indicate who I should be speaking to regarding this?
>
> Thank you,
>
> Serene